# Consulta para listar todos los Inicios de Sesión en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tego el siguiente script que encontré en internet para listar usuarios y roles dentro de una instancia de SQL Sever, el problema es que solo me arroja usuarios que tienen asignado alguna base de datos dentro del servidor, pero obvia muchos de los que solo tienen acceso de lectura (ninguna base de datos), entiendo que este último hace referencia a los login's, pero no encuentro nada concreto en la red.

```
    DECLARE @DB_USers TABLE
    (
        DBName sysname, 
        UserName sysname, 
        LoginType sysname, 
        AssociatedRole varchar(max),
        create_date datetime,
        modify_date datetime
    )

    INSERT @DB_USers
    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 
    '
        USE [?]
        SELECT  ''?'' AS DBName,
                case prin.name when ''dbo'' then prin.name + isnull((select SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) 
                                                                    from master.sys.databases 
                                                                    where name =''?''),'''')  
                    else prin.name end AS UserName,
                prin.type_desc AS LoginType,
                isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'''') AS AssociatedRole,
                create_date,
                modify_date

        FROM    sys.database_principals prin
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem 
                    ON prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id

        WHERE   prin.sid IS NOT NULL and 
                prin.sid NOT IN (0x00) and
                prin.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND 
                prin.name NOT LIKE ''##%''

    '

    SELECT  dbname,
            username ,logintype ,create_date ,modify_date ,

    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),associatedrole)
            FROM @DB_USers user2
            WHERE   user1.DBName=user2.DBName AND 
                    user1.UserName=user2.UserName
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,1,''
    ) AS Permissions_user

    FROM @DB_USers user1

    GROUP BY dbname,username ,logintype ,create_date ,modify_date
    ORDER BY DBName,username
    --------------------------------------------------------------
```

He intentado modificar este script sin éxito, cualquier sugerencia sería de mucha ayuda.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te puedan servir las siguientes consultas simples, aunque algunas versiones de SQL Server no las soportan:

```
SELECT * from master.sys.sql_logins

SELECT * from master.sys.sysusers
```

Comment: Una pregunta, el anteponer master en la segunda consulta, entiendo que solo me arrojará usuarios de esa base de datos, ¿O es el resumen de todas las demás BD's?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-logins-transact-sql y de las tablas maestras: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database